# why parent shell does not really finish (becomes "S" ) after spawning a subshell using parenthsis?

Tags: bash

Recently, I noticed that "(cmd list)" will make the current (parent) shell become defunct until the subshell quit. I would be grateful if someone can tell me why it is the case.

Here is how to reproduce it:

```
  $ cat test.sh
  #!/bin/bash

  (echo hello; sleep 60 )&

  $ ./test.sh
  hello

  $ ps aux | grep -i '\(test.sh\|sleep\)'
  dsuser   32621  0.0  0.0 113124   700 pts/0    S    00:56   0:00 /bin/bash ./test.sh
  dsuser   32622  0.0  0.0 107896   620 pts/0    S    00:56   0:00 sleep 60
  dsuser   32624  0.0  0.0 112644  1012 pts/0    R+   00:56   0:00 grep --color=auto -i \(test.sh\|sleep\)

  $ pkill sleep
  ./test.sh: line 3: 32622 Terminated              sleep 60

  $ ps aux | grep -i '\(test.sh\|sleep\)'
  dsuser   32627  0.0  0.0 112644  1012 pts/0    R+   00:57   0:00 grep --color=auto -i \(test.sh\|sleep\)
```

Please note that "test.sh" exists until the subshell (sleep) was killed. Also note that, in the following test, the "test.sh" is reap immediately.

```
  $ cat test.sh
  #!/bin/bash

  echo hello; sleep 60 &

  $ ./test.sh
  hello

  $ ps aux | grep -i '\(test.sh\|sleep\)'

  dsuser   32631  0.0  0.0 107896   620 pts/0    S    00:57   0:00 sleep 60
  dsuser   32633  0.0  0.0 112644  1012 pts/0    S+   00:57   0:00 grep --color=auto -i \(test.sh\|sleep\)
```

Answer (score 1):

The parent process remains in the process table until its children complete.  At that point it's reaped.  This is just part of how process management works in Unixy systems (some variance applies).  You could just execute the command within the same shell using the `exec` command instead if you want the command to replace the parent process.

Comment: Thanks. But, won't the process be reaped immediately and its child processes will be adopted by init (process 1)? If run "sleep 60&" directly (without parenthsis, see the updated question), I can see that the parent process reaped immediately